# Why is SQL query with between filter on Id than top 1 row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Log` table in my database which has an enormous amount of data. So when I get the last inserted row, it takes about 5 seconds.

But when I run query with 500 results with between filter with Ids, it runs faster. How is that possible?

This is the query I am running:

```
select top 1 * 
from log 
order by date desc

declare @temp_no bigint = 12215280

select * 
from log 
where id between (@temp_no - 500) and @temp_no 
order by date desc
```

Comment: I am asking about why is performance difference between both queries? not asking for any corrections in the code @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: @hsn . . . You should write that as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: For SQL performance help, you need to [edit] your question and add table and index definitions, and share the query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: id is most likely indexed and date is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have an index on `id` column but don't have any index on `date` column so
DBMS should sort all records each time you execute the first query. But for the second query it only sorts 500 records. Anyway, to find the exact reason you should look at the `query plan` of each query.